# ASP .NET expressions (inline tag) with String.Format

Tags: asp.net

I was juste wondering if it was possible to use `String.Format` with the following inline tag :

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="tbTest" Text="<%$ Resources:ErrorMsg, E3032  %>" runat="server" />
```

like this so

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="tbTest" Text='<%= String.Format(<%$ Resources:ErrorMsg, E3032  %>, "Other Text to insert")' runat="server" />
```

I know you can't do that but it's just for the picture.

tx

Comment: Wouldn't the other text to insert also need to come from the resource file?

Comment: Good point! But not for the situation I'm working on. :)

Comment: does Resources:ErrorMsg give out a format type string? Give us an example of its output.

Comment: output would be something like : "{0} is required."
so I would like String.Format(<%$ Resources:ErrorMsg, E3032 %>, "Name") to give me "Name is required".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own expression for this purpose :

web.config :

```
<expressionBuilders>
  <add expressionPrefix="CreerMsgErreur" type="MsgErreurs, App_Code" /> 
</expressionBuilders>
```

.aspx :

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="tbdDateFin"
 CssClass="test" Text="<%$ CreerMsgErreur:E3033, insert, date %>"
 ErrorMessage="<%$ CreerMsgErreur:E3033, insert, date %>"
 runat="server" EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="true" />
```

.vb :

```
Imports System
Imports System.CodeDom
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Compilation
Imports System.Web.UI

<ExpressionPrefix("Reflect")> _
<AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Level:=AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)> _
<AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Level:=AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)> _
Public Class MsgErreurs
    Inherits ExpressionBuilder

    Public Overrides Function GetCodeExpression(ByVal entry As System.Web.UI.BoundPropertyEntry, ByVal parsedData As Object, ByVal context As System.Web.Compilation.ExpressionBuilderContext) As System.CodeDom.CodeExpression
        If parsedData IsNot Nothing Then
            Return New CodePrimitiveExpression(CType(parsedData, MsgErreursParse).ToString())
        End If

        Return New CodePrimitiveExpression("Erreur de l'expression")
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ParseExpression(ByVal expression As String, ByVal propertyType As System.Type, ByVal context As System.Web.Compilation.ExpressionBuilderContext) As Object

        Dim leMsgErreur As MsgErreursParse = Nothing

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(expression) Then
            leMsgErreur = New MsgErreursParse(expression)
        Else
            Throw New HttpException(String.Format("Message de l'expression MsgErreur vous devez entrer une expression."))
        End If

        Return leMsgErreur
    End Function

    Private Class MsgErreursParse
        Private mNoErreur As String
        Private mParametres As String

        Public Property NoErreur() As String
            Get
                Return mNoErreur
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                mNoErreur = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Parametres() As String
            Get
                Return mParametres
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                mParametres = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New(ByVal parametres As String)
            Try
                mNoErreur = parametres.Substring(0, parametres.IndexOf(",")).Trim()
                mParametres = parametres.Substring(parametres.IndexOf(",") + 1).Trim()
            Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                mNoErreur = parametres
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(mNoErreur) Then
                Throw New HttpException(String.Format("Message de l'expression MsgErreur : vous devez spécifier un code d'erreur ou les paramètres ne sont pas dans le bon format : {0}", parametres))
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal noErreur As String, ByVal parametres As String)
            mNoErreur = noErreur
            mParametres = parametres
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Try
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Parametres) Then
                    Return Convert.ToString(HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MsgErreurs", NoErreur), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                Else
                    Return String.Format(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MsgErreurs", NoErreur), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), Parametres.Split(",").Select(Function(s) s.Trim()).ToArray())
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New HttpException(String.Format("Message de l'expression MsgErreur : impossible de créer le message d'erreur : NoErreur : {0}, Parametres : {1}", NoErreur, Parametres))
            End Try
        End Function
    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

The resources binding syntax is limited to only accepting two parameters: the name of the resource container and the resource key.


You can use an the data binding

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
       ControlToValidate="tbTest" 
       Text='<%# String.Format(
                     Convert.ToString(GetGlobalResourceObject("ErrorMsg", "E3032"), 
                     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                         "Other Text to insert") %>'
        />
```

You might need to call tbTest.DataBind() if the control is not a child of a databainding control.

Comment: didn't like too much the solution bc I didn't want to call DataBind() for each validator. Might as well do everything from codebehind but then I tried Page.DataBind() in page_load and it worked. cool. Just hope it won't interfer with other databound control.